# Can you check in more luggage than allowance at a layover without charge?

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, layovers

I'm on a long-haul flight with origin `A`, layover at `B` and destination `C`. Let's say on both legs I have 30 kgs allowance. I have my 30 kg bag checked from `A` to `C`.

Could I buy stuff at `B` (up to 30 kgs) and check that in as my allowance from `B` to `C` or would I have to pay carriage for whatever I buy at `B`?

Comment: I am/was trying to figure out if luggage could be 'hacked'

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because this just makes no sense.

Comment: I am confused by what `Could I buy stuff at the B - C leg?` actually means. On simple multi-flight bookings, you just check in some luggage in A and pick it up at C, and the same rules apply for both flights. period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The luggage allowance with your ticket is for *all* your flights together. Any luggage you check as you depart A has to be within your allowance. Once you leave B, that luggage will *still* be loaded onto the plane and will count just the same.

Conceivably, you can also pay for additional luggage. People usually do it on departure from the first stop but you might be allowed to buy more allowance at B and have it checked in. That might require you to get out of the terminal area to get to where baggage is dropped off, it depends on the airport's layout.

The exact policies depends on the airline but usually you have a weight allowance and number items you are allowed to check. Most airlines specify weight per item but LATAM specifies a total weight for all items. So if you have an allowance of 46kg and you checked in 24kg, you could add another item for 22kg. The [actual rules](https://www.latam.com/en_un/travel-information/baggage/checked-baggage/) are rather complicated and depend on the route. This is the first time I found rules that work this way but I supposed there might be other airlines doing similar things.